# ASP.NET in debug mode gets random timeouts against a local SQL Server 2019 database

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, debugging, timeout

This problem occurs only in debug mode with my ASP.NET MVC application. In release mode, everything is ok.

In debug mode, I can pass through my login process let's say 2 out of 10 times. All I usually get is a timeout on a Linq query (EF6) applied on a 50000 rows database table. Is there any options in Visual Studio that would explain this?

It usually takes a few (long) seconds between me clicking on a button and the controller's method being called. And when I'm debugging and try to execute a linq query, I get SQL Server timeouts a lot of times.

Deleting the web site cache helps a little but something else is wrong, probably with Visual Studio itself